# concatenate a MethodCallExpression on MemberExpression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I wish to Create the following Linq expression using Expression tree:

```
var result2 = soldiers.OrderByDescending(soldier => soldier.Ranks.OrderBy(r=> r.Date).FirstOrDefault().Date).ToArray() ;
```

***The models are listed at the end of the question***

I tried to do the following:

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Soldier), "soldier");

// e.g soldier.ranks
MemberExpression rank = Expression.Property(pe, "ranks");

ParameterExpression nestedParams = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Rank), "rank");

var dateProperty = typeof(Rank).GetProperty("Date");

// e.g rank.Date
MemberExpression nestedExpression= Expression.MakeMemberAccess(nestedParams, dateProperty);

// e.g rank => rank.date
var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<Rank, DateTime?>>(nestedExpression, nestedParams);

MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression2 = Expression.Call(
typeof(Queryable),
"OrderByDescending",
 new Type[] { typeof(Rank), typeof(DateTime?) },
 rank, ***// i suspect the problem is in this line #110***
 orderByExp);
```

But the following error has been thorwn:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No generic method 'OrderByDescending' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic. '
```

As I wrote in the code's comments, I suspect that the problem occurs becuase of line 110.
I tried to concatenate the orderBy method on the *`soldier.ranks`* property.
But perhaps becuase the `soldier.ranks is MemberExpression instead of MethodCallExpression or Queryable, i couldn't preformed that action.

I used both links as reference but could find, anything similler to my problem.
* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries

*https://stackoverflow.com/a/11337472/10950549

***models:***

```
public class Soldier
{
    public Rank Rank {
        get {
            return this.Ranks.OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public ICollection<Rank> Ranks { get; set; }
}

public class Rank
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

thanks,

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621676/accessing-expression-bodied-members-to-build-expression-trees)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I suspect that the problem occurs because of line 110

```
MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression2 = Expression.Call(
typeof(Queryable),
"OrderByDescending",
 new Type[] { typeof(Rank), typeof(DateTime?) },
 rank, ***// i suspect the problem is in this line #110***
 orderByExp);
```

Nope, the problem is the `Queryable` 3 lines above:

```
typeof(Queryable),
```

It doesn't matter what exact type of expression (member, method call etc.) `rank` is, the important is what is the type of the result of that expression (i.e. `Expression.Type`). And the type of `soldier.Ranks` is `ICollection<Rank>` - definitely not `IQueryable<Rank>`, hence the exception.

But as we know, `ICollection<T>` inherits (is a) `IEnumerable<T>`, hence `oldier.Ranks.OrderBy` is actually call to `Enumerable.OrderBy` rather than `Queryable.OrderBy`.

With that being said, simply change `Queryable` to `Enumerable` in the aforementioned line and this particular problem will be solved.